# Show that two white noise definitions are equivalent

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, white-noise

Given $(\varepsilon_t)\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$ a white noise. By definition
$$E(\varepsilon_t)=0,\,\, E(\varepsilon_t^2)=\sigma^2 \quad \forall t$$
and
$$E(\varepsilon_t \varepsilon_s) = 0, \quad s\neq t$$

I want to show that this equivalent to
$$E(\varepsilon_t |\varepsilon_s)=0$$

The intuition of one direction is ok. If $\varepsilon_t$ and $\varepsilon_s$ are ortogonal,i.e. $E(\varepsilon_t \varepsilon_s) = 0$, then the projection $E(\varepsilon_t |\varepsilon_s)=0$. But I don't know how to formally prove it.

The reciprocal or another direction I can't prove either.

Help

Comment: I doubt you can prove it, because it's not true.  [Don't you also want to assume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#White_noise_vector) the different $\varepsilon_t$ are independent?  If you don't, you could take a white noise process on the real numbers with Bernoulli$(1/2)$ distributions and redefine it by $\varepsilon_{-t}=1-\varepsilon_t$ for all $t\gt 0.$ It looks like it still satisfies all your requirements, but $E(\varepsilon_{-1}\mid \varepsilon_1)=1-\varepsilon_1\ne 0.$

Comment: But this process does not have mean zero!

Comment: Subtract $1/2$ from it then.  Yes, that doesn't quite work--but the underlying idea does: create dependencies among the $\varepsilon_t$ so that what you want to prove is false but all your assumptions are true.

Comment: @whuber if the different $\varepsilon_t$ are independent, is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. As a counterexample, let $(u_t)_{t\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $u_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Define the stochastic process $(a_t)_{t\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}$ as follows:

$$a_t =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  u_t  & \mbox{if } t \equiv0 \mod 2 \\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u_{t-1}^2 - 1) & \mbox{if } t \equiv 1 \mod 2
 \end{array}
\right. \quad.
$$

It is straightforward to show that $\mathbb{E}[a_t] = 0$ and $Var(a_t) = 1$ for all $t$ (use $E[u_t^4] = 3$ for odd $t$). Moreover,
$$\mathbb{E}[a_{2t}a_{2t+1}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mathbb{E}[u_{2t}^3 - u_{2t}] = 0 \quad.$$

For the other values of $t,s \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}$ with $t \neq s$, you can show that $\mathbb{E}[a_{t}a_{s}] = 0$ just by verifying that it is the expected product different $u_t$, which is $0$. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[a_{t}a_{s}] = 0$ for all $t,s \, \in \, \mathbb{Z}$ with $t \neq s$.

Finally, notice that $a_{2r} = u_{2r}$ and $a_{2r+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u_{2r}^2 - 1)$ for any $r\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}$, so
$$\mathbb{E}[a_{2r+1}|a_{2r}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a_{2r}^2 - 1) \quad, $$

which concludes the argument.

Comment: When they are equivalent?

Comment: I do not know which additional condition you could impose so that they become equivalent. Assuming independence would imply both conditions, but it is not the same as saying they are equivalent.